# Schedule a task in ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, scheduled-tasks, webmethod

I have an ASP.NET application which runs in Windows Server 2003.

In this application I have a web service method which sends a notification email to interested parties. This web method is (most likely) triggered by a scheduled task that runs every Monday.

The problem is that I have to change the frequency of the scheduled task but I cannot find any task under Windows Scheduled Tasks. My only guess is that the task is somehow scheduled inside the ASP.NET application. Is it realistic or is there any other way to schedule tasks for ASP.NET applications beside the Windows Scheduled Tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .NET `Timer` or scheduling framework like Quartz .NET (http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked to this kind of services? [ATrigger](http://atrigger.com/)

Disclaimer: I was among the ATrigger team. It's a freeware and I have not any commercial purpose.

Comment: what happens when ATrigger hits soft timeout?

Comment: @John Just in case if website doesn't reply in 5 seconds.

Comment: what if it is a web site running large script for approx 5 mins. Will it trigger timeout on trigger?

Comment: @John After 5 seconds it will be considered as a done task(soft error timeout), so ATrigger will not fire it again because of error.

Comment: @Kousha our scripts took more than 5 seconds but less than 10 seconds, and your 5 seconds timeout is causing our script execution to stop. is it possible to increase the timeout or what do you suggest?